# Bash script which compares number obtained from a cut

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I have a string like this

```
"Hello catch these numbers 20 30"
```

And I have:

```
NUMBER_ONE=$(echo "$line" | cut -d' ' -f5)
NUMBER_TWO=$(echo "$line" | cut -d' ' -f6)
```

When I compare `if [ "$NUMBER_ONE" -gt  "$NUMBER_TWO" ];` I got error, it  expects an integer expression. How do I solve?

Comment: that comparison should work if `$line` contains the string you say it does.  try posting the actual definition of $line and the other variables - add the output of `typeset -p line NUMBER_ONE NUMBER_TWO | cat -A` to your question (not in a comment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the variable `line` contains *exactly* what you have shown, then `$NUMBER_TWO` would be `30"`, including the double quote. This is clearly not an integer.

Instead,

```bash
line='"Hello catch these numbers 20 30"'

if [[ $line =~ ([[:digit:]]+)" "([[:digit:]]+) ]]; then
    NUMBER_ONE=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    NUMBER_TWO=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}

    if (( NUMBER_ONE > NUMBER_TWO )); then
        echo NUMBER_ONE is greater than NUMBER_TWO
    else
        echo NUMBER_ONE is not greater than NUMBER_TWO
    fi
fi
```

This uses a regular expression to match the two space-separated (positive) integers as substrings of digits, and then performs the comparison.  The double quote after `30` will not be matched.

---

If you still want to use tools from the standard toolbox, then simply strip out any non-digits from the variables as you assign them, using `tr`.  Modifying your old code slightly:

```bash
NUMBER_ONE=$(cut -d' ' -f 5 <<<"$line" | tr -dc '[:digit:]' )
NUMBER_TWO=$(cut -d' ' -f 6 <<<"$line" | tr -dc '[:digit:]' )
```

or do it afterwards using a `bash` substitution,

```bash
NUMBER_ONE=$(cut -d' ' -f 5 <<<"$line" ); NUMBER_ONE=${NUMBER_ONE//[![:digit:]]/}
NUMBER_TWO=$(cut -d' ' -f 6 <<<"$line" ); NUMBER_TWO=${NUMBER_TWO//[![:digit:]]/}
```

Note that if you need to deal with negative integers, then you obviously should not strip out the minus sign (and in the regular expression match in the first code snippet above, you would have to allow for an initial minus sign too).

Answer (score -1):

Tried with below script and it worked too

```
NUMBER_ONE=`sed 's/"//g'  o.txt| awk '{print $(NF-1)}'`
NUMBER_TWO=`sed 's/"//g'  o.txt| awk '{print $NF}'`

if [[ $NUMBER_ONE -gt $NUMBER_TWO ]]; 
then 
echo "$NUMBER_ONE is greater than NUMBER_TWO"; 
else 
echo "NUMBER_ONE is equal or less than NUMBER_TWO";


fi
```

Comment: please learn to don't combine text-processing tools with each other as those each one are strong enough to do the same with itself alone. please use `$(...)` "command substitution" instead of old style `\`...\``.

Comment: You seem to be missing a `$` in your test. You don't need it since `bash` would evaluate the variables in an arithmetic context, but it look strange when you leave the `$` from one variable and not the other.

Comment: @Kusalananda Corrected the code